# Not able to see remote branches in local

Tags: git, bitbucket, branching-and-merging, remote-repository

I have tried all the possible ways

```
git fetch origin
git fetch --all
```

But I am not able to see any of the remote branches in my local.

```
C:\Jboss_WP_TN_MAVEN\tdhs_ebms_wp>git branch -r
  origin/feature/tdhs_ebms_wp_feature
```

Answer (score 0):

`git remote -v` should show you if your remote is properly set. If it isn't, do: `git remote add origin git@github.com:someUser/someRepo.git`

Follow that with a `git fetch` so your client is aware of remote changes.

`git branch --remote` should list all the remote branches known by your client. To list branches, you shouldn't append a branch name to your command.

Comment: @Icoderre  thank you so much for the response .But what dooes that someUser and someRepo should be replaced with

Comment: C:\Jboss_WP_TN_MAVEN\tdhs_ebms_wp>git remote -v
origin  https://bitbucket.dhs.tn.gov/scm/ebms/tdhs_ebms_wp.git (fetch)
origin  https://bitbucket.dhs.tn.gov/scm/ebms/tdhs_ebms_wp.git (push)